# Random number and array search

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am attempting to generate an ADDITIONAL single random number and create another method that will have three parameters = the integer array, the size of the array, and the value it will be searching for in the array. It will search through the array and count how many times the value was found.It will then either print out how many times the value was found or that the value was not found. I am a bit lost and this is what I have so far which generates the random array and prints it/ asking the user if they want to restart. Thanks in advance

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class Main{
public static final Random RND_GEN = new Random();
public void createNum(int[] randomNumbers) {

for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
    randomNumbers[i] = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
}
}

public void printNum(int[] randomNumbers){
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
}
}

public void run() {
Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = 1;
do {
    int[] number = new int[20];
    createNum(number);
    printNum(number);
    System.out.print("Restart Program?, Enter 1 for YES, 2 for NO: ");            
    x = inputReader.nextInt();
} while (x == 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Main go = new Main();
go.run();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should not be telling you the whole code, since this looks like a homework question.

So here are the hints:

- Creating an additional random number - Not so difficult, as you have `RND_GEN`

  ```
  int rn = RND_GEN.nextInt(10)+1; //exactly as you have been doing it.
  ```
- Creating a method that takes three parameters.... Here is the method header:

  ```
  void search(int[] array, int size, int val)
  ```
- Body of the method? You have various search algorithms out there. Some of the most popular ones are:

  - [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search)
  - [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

So just go on, **research**, **learn** and **do it yourself**.

Comment: Thank you! I got the single random number generated, on to the search now but thank you for the kickstart!