# array search and count

Tags: java, arrays, search, methods

I am developing a program that will search through my array for how many times my single random # appears and then print how many times or that it was not found. I have been researching ways to do this and cannot seem to get it figured out. This is what I have so far and thanks in advance.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class Main {
  public static final Random RND_GEN = new Random();

  public void createNum(int[] randomNumbers) {  
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
      randomNumbers[i] = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      randomNumbers[i] = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
    }
  } 

  public void printNum(int[] randomNumbers){
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      System.out.println("Single Random # " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
    }
  }


  public void run() {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 1;
    do {
      int[] number = new int[20];
      createNum(number);
      printNum(number);
      System.out.print("Restart Program?, Enter 1 for YES, 2 for NO: ");            
      x = inputReader.nextInt();
    } while (x == 1);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main go = new Main();
    go.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is in no way an answer to your question, but I *very strongly urge* you to indent your code. (Perhaps you do and the absence of indentation here is just because there was some problem about transferring the code into the SO question. But if not, you should. It will make it easier for everyone to read.)

Comment: (Thanks to Jean-Baptiste Yunès for fixing the indentation!)

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to have anything in it that actually attempts to do the search. You say you've been "researching ways to do this", so what have you looked at? Have you tried anything, and if so what went wrong?

Comment: What is your "single random number" ? I can see an array of random numbers, but what else?

Comment: I see! The first number in the array is "the single random number". So you must try to loop over the array and test if i-th item equals to 1st. You already know how to loop...

Comment: It seems like your code won't even compile as for the abstract method: `public void seachArray(int[] array, int size, int val);`

Comment: Code was edited, it will print out an array of 20 integers and then one additional random number which is labeled Single Random # when it prints out.

Comment: And I have found ways of binary and linear searches but simply do not know how to translate into code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static final Random RND_GEN = new Random();

    public int[] createNum(int[] randomNumbers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
            randomNumbers[i] = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
        }

        return randomNumbers;
    }

    public void printNum(int[] randomNumbers){
        for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
        }
    }

    public int findNumInstancesInArray(int[] array, int numLookingFor) {
        int count = 0;

        for(int i : array) {
            if (i == numLookingFor) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public void run() {
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        do {
            int[] numbers = new int[20];
            numbers = createNum(numbers);
            printNum(numbers);
            int numLookingFor = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
            System.out.println("Number of instances of " + numLookingFor + " is: " + findNumInstancesInArray(numbers, numLookingFor));
            System.out.print("Restart Program?, Enter 1 for YES, 2 for NO: ");
            x = inputReader.nextInt();
        } while (x == 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main go = new Main();
        go.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: When searching for the number, it is the single random number already generated so there is no user input: The method datatype is void because no data will be returned. 
It will have three parameters – the integer array, the size of the array, and the value it will be searching for in the array.  It will search through the array and count how many times the value was found.It will then either print out how many times the value was found or that the value was not found. @JSterling8

Comment: Then you can simply change:  int numLookingFor = inputReader.nextInt(); to int numLookingFor = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1; and remove the System.out that asks for a number.

Comment: I'm also genuinely confused as to why you accepted the other answer over mine.  I provided the method you were looking for, as well as showed you an example of how to use it in your current code structure.  My implementation of the method is also a lot easier to read than the accepted answer.

Comment: @JSterling8...because I am not very intelligent when it comes to looking at code or developing it. Most people on here would probably laugh but it took me like 10 hours to figure what I had got so far. This is not my strong suit and sorry if I offended you by not accepting your answer, I see now how it will help me figure this all out and in the future so thank you.

Comment: And the answer still does not provide the required information. My code prints out an array of 20 integers and then another single random number, the code must then count how many times that other single random number is found in the array of 20 integers..@JSterling8

Comment: @kidbone222 - No offense taken.  I was just confused.  Thank you for accepting my answer.  I've updated the run() method to be closer to what you asked for in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can count an element in an `int` array:

```
public int countOccurrences(int[] array, int needle) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; array[++index] == needle ? count++ : count);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if this is the search part of your other question posted here: [Random number and array search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573425/random-number-and-array-search)

There, you were suggested to learn about linear search and binary search. If you did, it shouldn't be too hard to translate linear search into code (binary search won't help you here). You simply have to loop through the array (you're code proves you know how to do that) and check every value if it equals the one you're searching for. Of course, if you want to count the hits, you have to increase a counter every time the value matches.